# How to compare 2 converted dates in sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to exclude results in my query that start in the same month between two columns. For example, I need to exclude benefits1 that start in the same month as benefits2. Format for benefit1_start_date and benefit2_start_date is: YYYYMMDD.

This is what I have so far:

```
where (benefit1_start_date = (to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') || '0122')) <> 
(benefit2_start_date = (to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') || '0122'));
```

If anyone could put me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Is `benefit1_start_date` a date column, or is it text?

Comment: Format for both is number(8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your numeric dates to text, and then compare the year and month substrings:

```
WHERE
    SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(benefits1_start_date), 1, 6) <> SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(benefits2_start_date), 1, 6)
```

Note that storing your dates as numbers like this is atypical, and you might want to consider storing them as dates.  If you don't have a day component, you could just use the first as a placeholder.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I get an error: MONTH invalid identifier.

Comment: @casper1111 Please reload your page.

Comment: My apologizes. I will try that now.

Comment: One more thing, @Tim Biegeleisen, could you explain the 1, 6 part?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to eliminate records where your 2 columns benefits1_start_date and benefits2_start_date are in the same month, and both have a format of YYYYMMDD.

Are they stored as strings? If so, all you need to do is compare the first 6 characters (if you need to consider yr + month), or just the 5+6th characters if you want to check just the month without the year.

Year + Month:
SUBSTR(benefits1_start_date,1,6) <> SUBSTR(benefits2_start_date,1,6)

Just month:

SUBSTR(benefits1_start_date,5,2) <> SUBSTR(benefits2_start_date,5,2)

If they're not stored as strings but as dates, then you can TRUNC the date to month and compare (for yr + month), or convert the date to MM string via to_char and compare if you just want to check the month.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `BETWEEN` clause. Converting LEFT side operand to string by function and then making comparison can have severe performance impacts.

if you convert indexed table.dateColumn to string by to_char(table.dateColumn), oracle cannot use defined index on column anymore.

Your desired query:

```
where to_char(benefit1_start_date, 'YYYYMM') != to_char(benefit2_start_date, 'YYYYMM')
```

but

```
select * from table1
where months_between(benefit1_start_date, benefit2_start_date) not between -1 and 1
```

would be what you are looking for. (no performance impact)